# How to use Chunk Size for kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLTableDataSet in the kedro pipeline?

Tags: kedro

I am using kedro.extras.datasets.pandas.SQLTableDataSet and would like to use the chunk_size argument from pandas. However, when running the pipeline, the table gets treated as a generator instead of a pd.dataframe().

How would you use the chunk_size within the pipeline?

My catalog:

```
table_name:
  type: pandas.SQLTableDataSet
  credentials: redshift
  table_name : rs_table_name
  layer: output
  save_args:
    if_exists: append
    schema: schema.name
    chunk_size: 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the latest `pandas` doc, the actual `kwarg` to be used is `chunksize`, not `chunk_size`. Please see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html.
Since `kedro` only wraps your `save_args` and passes them to `pd.DataFrame.to_sql` these need to match:

```py
def _save(self, data: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    try:
        data.to_sql(**self._save_args)
    except ImportError as import_error:
        raise _get_missing_module_error(import_error) from import_error
    except NoSuchModuleError as exc:
        raise _get_sql_alchemy_missing_error() from exc
```

EDIT: Once you have this working in your pipeline, the docs show that `pandas.DataFrame.read_sql` with `chunksize` set will return type `Iterator[DataFrame]`. This means that in your node function, you should iterate over the input (and annotate accordingly, if appropriate) such as:

```py
def my_node_func(input_dfs: Iterator[pd.DataFrame], *args):
  for df in input_dfs:
    ...
```

This works for the latest version of `pandas`. I have noticed, however, that `pandas` is aligning the API so that `read_csv` with `chunksize` set returns a `ContextManager` from `pandas>=1.2` so I would expect this change to occur in `read_sql` as well.